# Looping a write command to output many different indices from a list separately in Python

Tags: python, list

Im trying to get an output like:

```
KPLR003222854-2009131105131
```

in a text file. The way I am attempting to derive that output is as such:

```
with open('Processed_Data.txt', 'r') as file_P, open('KIC_list.txt', 'w') as namelist:
    nameData = []           
    for line in file_P:
        splt_file_P = line.split()
        nameData.append(splt_file_P[0])
    for key in nameData:
        namelist.write('\n' 'KPLR00' + "".join(str(w) for w in nameData) + '-2009131105131')
```

However I am having an issue in that the numbers in the nameData array are all appearing at once in the specified output, instead of using on ID cleanly as shown above the output is something like this:

```
KPLR00322285472138721382172198371823798123781923781237819237894676472634973256279234987-2009131105131
```

So my question is how do I loop the write command in a way that will allow me to get each separate ID (each has a specific index value, but there are over 150) to be properly outputted.

EDIT:
Also, some of the ID's in the list are not the same length, so I wanted to add 0's to the front of the 'key' to make them all equal 9 digits. I cheated this by adding the 0's into the KPLR in quotes but not all of the ID's need just two 0's. The question is, could I add 0's between KPLR and the key in any way to match the 9-digit format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks like it's working as one would expect: `"".join(str(w) for w in nameData)` makes a string composed of the concatenation of every item in `nameData`.

Chances are you want;

```
for key in nameData:
    namelist.write('\n' 'KPLR00' + key + '-2009131105131')
```

Or even better:

```
for key in nameData:
    namelist.write('\nKPLR%09i-2009131105131'%int(key)) #no string concatenation
```

String concatenation tends to be slower, and if you're not only operating on strings, will involve explicit calls to `str`. Here's a pair of ideone snippets showing the difference: http://ideone.com/RR5RnL and http://ideone.com/VH2gzx

Also, the above form with the format string `'%09i'` will pad with 0s to make the number up to 9 digits. Because the format is `'%i'`, I've added an explicit conversion to `int`.  See here for full details: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations

Finally, here's a single line version (excepting the `with` statement, which you should of course keep):

```
namelist.write("\n".join("KPLR%09i-2009131105131"%int(line.split()[0]) for line in file_P))
```

Comment: What's better about the second version?

Comment: @interjay Avoids string concatenation, so it tends to be faster.

Comment: Did you test it? It's actually slower for me. I don't know why you think concatenation would be slower than formatting. Besides, speed is irrelevant here, readability is more important.

Comment: @interjay I didn't test it. However, I also find templates easier to read.

Comment: @interjay Testing on ideone shows the template version to be faster.

Comment: It's slower on my computer, and in any case its speed is completely irrelevant when you're doing file I/O.

Comment: @interjay That's not actually true.

Comment: Well I can't argue with such a convincing argument.

Comment: @interjay It's slightly better than your assertion. I disagree with your unsupported claim.

Comment: @Marcin Thanks for this Marcin, I have added a small edit to address one other problem I'm having, if you could kindly take a look, thanks.

Comment: I'm curious if you have any references for templates being faster. I know they're more "pythonic", and a lot of people find them more readable, which is often a good enough reason to use them. But I've always assumed (without checking) that they are slower because the interpreter has to parse the string and then copy data. With string concatenation, it shouldn't be much more involved than just copying data.

Comment: @ImmortalxR A snap with templates. I've updated the answer to show the format string you want.

Comment: @sh1ftst0rm Lots of object allocation is time-expensive.

Comment: @Marcin That last edit is giving me an error Marcin: %d format: a number is required, not list

Comment: @ImmortalxR You never show your input or intermediate values or types, so it is more difficult to help you. However, the answer is that you need to use `int` to convert to an int.

Answer (score 0):

You can change this:

```
"".join(str(w) for w in nameData)
```

to this:

```
",".join(str(w) for w in nameData)
```

Basically, the "," will comma delimit the elements in your `nameData` list.  If you use `""`, then there will be nothing to separate the elements, so they appear all at once.  You can change the delimiter to suit your needs.

Comment: Almost positive that's not what his issue is. See Marcin's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just for kicks:

```
with open('Processed_Data.txt', 'r') as file_P, open('KIC_list.txt', 'w') as namelist:
    nameData = [line.split()[0] for line in file_P]
    namelist.write("\n".join("KPLR00" + str(key) + '-2009131105131' for key in nameData))
```

I think that will work, but I haven't tested it. You can make it even smaller/uglier by not using nameData at all, and just use that list comprehension right in its place.

Comment: You could do it in one line: `namelist.write("\n".join("KPLR00%s-2009131105131"%line.split()[0] for line in file_P))`

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I wrote in the answer, right after the code sample.